# How to get size occupied by each of the directories underneath a root directory?

Tags: linux

How to get size occupied by each of the directories underneath a root directory in GIGA BYTEs in a linux OEL environment

In AIX , I can give du -sg * to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the du command, like this:

`du -csh --block-size=1G \*` for the root of the filesystem

If you want human readeable values, use this:

`du -sh \*` again for the root of the filesystem